# Error in For Loop - Swift Language

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I am copying this very simple line of code from Apple's swift tutorial, but it generates the following error:

**.. is unavailable: half open range operator .. has been renamed to ..<** 
(strangely, .. is NOT renamed to ..<)

```
var firstForLoop = 0
for i in 0..3 {
    firstForLoop += i
}
```

I have tried adding "var":

```
for var i in 0..3 {
    firstForLoop += i
}
```

And somewhat counterintuitively, that results in "i" being unidentified! I would expect i to be unidentified in the first loop, not the second.

Comment: Well, this is pretty obvious, replace `0..3` in your code with `0..<3`. Apple renamed the operator

Comment: you should use `..<` instead of `..`, and i don't understand your question.

Comment: for number in 0..3{ try

Comment: You can download a current version of the Swift book, it has already been updated for the beta 4 release. The change is also documented in the beta 4 release notes.

Comment: I didn't know how to interpret the error message. It mentions that .. is replaced. I didn't realize that means that the operator is actually replaced in the swift language!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using older knowledge/documentation/code with a newer release of the Swift language.  The half-closed range operator changed to `..<` with the closed range operator remaining as `...`.  Thus use:

```
for i in 0..<3 { /* ... */ }
```

In action:

```
> for i in 0..<3 { print (i) }
0
1
2
```